# Validar Subcuadriculas de un sudoku

Tags: python

Hola tengo que programar una función que me compruebe que una subcuadricula de un Sudoku contenga todos los números del 1 al 9, este código que he programado no se porque siempre me devuelve false aunque el sudoku que le inserte esta solucionado.
Tengo un .txt con numeros en forma de 9 x 9 tal que así:

```
647259381
893761524
521843976
168594732
734128695
259637148
982315467
316472859
475986213
```

Entonces a este .txt le aplico esta función:

```
def llegirSudoku(s):
    """
    Es comproba si el fitxer donat existeix, si existeix es es retorna una matriu amb la representació del Sudoku en format python.
    """
    try:
        fin = open(s, "r")
        text= fin.readlines()
        fin.close()

        r = []
        for linia in text:
            r.append(list(linia[:-1]))
        return r
    except IOError:
        print("Ho sento, el fitxer no existeix")
        return []
```

Y por ultimo la función con la que necesito ayuda porque siempre me da false.

```
def validaSubcuadricula(t, fil, col):
    
    nums = []
    
    
    for i in range(3):
       
        for j in range(3):
            
            nums.append(t[fil + i][col + j])
    
    
    for i in range(1,10):
        if i not in nums:
            return False
    
    return True
```

Comment: Puede que tu matriz `t` contenga strings en lugar de enteros. Como no la publicas, es puro adivinar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando la misma matriz que en tu anterior pregunta, el problema es que comparas strings con enteros.

Este código verifica si la condición se cumple sin importar si usas strings o enteros:

```
def validaSubcuadricula(t, fil, col):
    nums = set()

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if t[fil + i][col + j]:
                nums.add(t[fil + i][col + j])

    return len(nums) == 9
```

En lugar de una lista uso un *set*, con lo que evito agregar elementos duplicados.

Una vez extraidos los elementos, basta comprobar que el set tenga 9 elementos. Si no, es que uno falta.

**Demo**

Para la demo suponemos que la falta de valor se representa con `None`.

```
def validaSubcuadricula(t, fil, col):
    nums = set()

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if t[fil + i][col + j]:
                nums.add(t[fil + i][col + j])

    return len(nums) == 9

t = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

print(validaSubcuadricula(t,0,0))

t = [[1, None, None],
     [4, 5, 5],
     [7, 8, 9]]

print(validaSubcuadricula(t,0,0))
```

produce:

```
True
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```